# HTML Table Export to Excel (Cells' contents do not fit)

Tags: excel, html-table, cell, export-to-excel

Is there any formatting I can use in HTML Table, for exporting data to Excel, which is exact fit in every cell.

Comment: not that I know the answer, but what do you mean by 'exact fit in every cell?' you mean the format that automatically makes the Excel file's cell size fit for its content? (the biggest content? maybe? because contents are different in general)

Comment: Yes. Automatically makes the Excel file's cell size fits for its content.

Comment: I don't know of any way without auto-fitting the columns manually after pasting, but it kind of works if you open html file with Excel instead of pasting it.